# qtonpi tag is flagged as unusable?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I was recently editing a question that used the [qtonpi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qtonpi) tag. When I had finished my edit I selected <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>, only to get this:

[image]

Obviously, I found this a bit strange, since [qtonpi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qtonpi) is an actual defined tag and has been used multiple times - and there is no 'pi' tag on this question.

I removed the offending tag and I was able to submit. Not sure if this is a bug in the tag detection algorithm thingy or what. Just thought I'd post about it.

Comment: What question did this happen on?

Comment: @SteveRobillard http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/compiling-qt-multimedia-for-raspberry-pi

Comment: I don't know if it is being considered a misspelling because the error only says Pi or something else. I would consider this a bug. You may want to ask this on the stackexchange meta.

Comment: It appears to have been a bug which is now fixed, can you try applying the tag again and letting me know if it worked?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yup, it's working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It really wasn't me it was @goldilocks and the SO staff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was found to be a bug, and is now fixed - thanks to @goldilocks and the SO staff.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks and SO staff!